# Mouse button still controls settings of other Synergy client when changing window

Tags: windows, macos, mouse, synergy

I'm using Synergy as the server on OS X Mountain Lion. Now I have a strange problem using a specic piece of software on the Mac. It is a program for viewing medical images ([Osirix](http://www.osirix-viewer.com/)).  The left mouse button controls brighness and contrast of the displayed images.

When leaving the screen to the (PC), the left mouse button actions still affect the settings of the (last active / highlighted) Mac window.

I'm not sure if this is a Synergy problem or an Osirix bug. I would suspect that any mouse actions on the client screen shoudn't have any effect on the server screen.

Changing server and client solves the problem, but I need the full mouse functionality and programable mouse buttons on the Mac side — this functionality is lost by making it the client.

Anybody out there expiriencing similar problems with imaging software? Any idea how to solve the problem?